# Any smart HTML5/CSS3 method to get a div to expand to fill the "client area"?

Tags: html, layout, css

I have a web page that uses dynamic widths (as in, it expands to occupy the entire browser area). Within this page I have a content container div in which I would like to have a fixed-width "left panel" and a dynamically sized center/right area.

```
<div id="content">
   <div class="left-panel">
   </div>
   <div class="center-panel">
   </div>
</div>
```

My problem is that when I set left-panel to a fixed width and center-panel to 100%, the latter will occupy the full width of the content div, rather than just the remaining area. I can work around this using margins, but was wondering if there isn't a smarter way of doing this with HTML5 and/or CSS3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I totally understand your question or not, but is this what you are after??? http://jsfiddle.net/maU5N/

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting back on this. Your example was spot on!

Answer (score 2):

I recently heard about [css3 flexbox](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-flexbox/). Haven't used it yet, but looks great. I also found this [very good tutorial](http://www.the-haystack.com/2012/01/04/learn-you-a-flexbox/).

Comment: According to http://html5please.com/ it's a bit early for that solution, but give it 6 months and you'd probably have gotten the mark :)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use Media queries to get the browser width and fix the width for each browser resolution.